# Запятая перед И (4)

Tags: запятые, и

Нужна ли запятая:

***Да, конечно, у нас под каждый размер шины своя заготовка и средние закончились.***

Будут ли в этом приложении "своя" и "средние" однородными членами предложения (условия для отсутствия запятой)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Мы рассматриваем ССП, в состав которого входят два простых предложения, связанных союзом И. Условием для постановки или отсутствия запятой пред союзом И  является наличие **общего элемента.**

***Да, конечно**, у нас под каждый размер шины своя заготовка, и средние закончились.*

Запятая ставится, так как "***да, конечно***" относится **только к первому предложению**  и не является общим элементом, а сообщение "средние закончились" — это уже отдельная информация.

2. **Примечание**

*Будут ли в этом приложении "своя" и "средние" однородными членами предложения (условия для отсутствия запятой)?*

**Это некорректное условие.**

В ССП входят два простых **предложения** (они **двусоставные неполные**), поэтому вопрос **об однородных членах** здесь вообще не стоит. Эта тема возможна только для **односоставных** предложений, которые действительно в некоторых случаях приравниваются к однородным.

Общий второстепенный член может находиться **в середине предложения**, но это одно и то же слово, а не однородные члены,  например: *Взгляд **ЕГО** был умным и в голосе (**его**) звучала сила. Ветер **К УТРУ** ослабел и снег (**к утру**) престал.*

Answer (score 2):

Предложение из двух неполных. В первом нет сказуемого, в другом — подлежащего; за запятой следует союз *и*, и его лучше не употреблять, т. к. сведения сильно разнятся (размеры и наличие).

*Да, конечно, у нас под каждый размер шины своя заготовка (*имеется*); средние — (*шины*/*размеры*) закончились.*

*Да, конечно, у нас под каждый размер шины своя заготовка, а средние — закончились.*